# Is it possible to pair with device constant pair key using core bluetooth

Tags: iphone, ios, core-bluetooth

In my iPhone application I would like to communicate with a firmware device. During a connection they can to ask for a pairing key but they said they are not having provision to provide what is the key to enter.

[image]

In this situation USP(User Smart Phone) never knows the key to enter. What shall we do to communicate with device ?

Comment: No they have given some passkey like 123456 if i give some other text it not getting paired

Comment: If your app is to communicate whith a specific device, user will have to read the manual of the device or you can show hil or her what´s the code to enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> they said they are not having provision to provide what is the key to enter

I'm not sure I completely understand this sentence but if the user is given a device that has a specific pin/key, then that has to be documented somewhere for them. This is the same situation as it is with a SIM card's PIN. That code is set by the manufacturer and the user gets to know it when she buys the card. If the code is the same for all devices, then you can add it to your application and show it to the user in some way.

The iPhone application cannot dismiss or enter any value in the pairing dialog, this is sure.